# Delegate painting of custom Swing component to parent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, custom-component

### My goal

I want my custom Swing component `CellLabel extends JLabel` to paint certain things (X) always, and certain other elements (Y) only if its parent - (a `JPanel` holding **a grid of `CellLabel`s**) - tells it to. The painting of (Y) depends on the state of the neighbouring cells in the grid, and only the `JPanel` can get this information and decide if **and how** (Y) should be painted for every child `CellLabel`.

### My question

How can I externalize (into a method with parameters that allow me to describe **how** to paint (Y) exactly) the painting behavior so that the parent can decide whether it wants a `CellLabel` child to paint (Y) or not?

### My problem

Every Swing tutorial out there tells me I should overwrite the `paintComponent` method when creating a custom component; however, in my application, the component can't decide for itself if and how (Y) should be painted since it lacks the necessary information.

I tried to write a `CellLabel::paintY(int offset)` method that I could call from the parent once it has decided how and if to paint (Y):

```
class CellLabel extends JLabel {
    void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Paint elements (X) which should always be painted, independent
        // of external state
    }        

    void paintY(int[] params){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();

        // Perform some calculation with params that decide how painting is done

        // (*) Actually paint elements (Y) by using the g2 graphics context
    }
}
```

However, it seems I can't get a hold of the `Graphics` context outside of the predefined `paint` methods that convention tells me to overwrite. I get the following exception at (*) (when actually trying to paint with g2):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at CellLabel.paintY(CellLabel.java:77)
at AutomatonUI.createAndShowGUI(AutomatonUI.java:50)
at AutomatonUI.access$000(AutomatonUI.java:22)
at AutomatonUI$1.run(AutomatonUI.java:29)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I have a solid amount of experience coding business logic and number-crunching, but I'm quite new to Swing (and UI programming) in general, so please excuse me (and educate me) if I'm doing something horribly wrong.

Comment: You custom component shouldn't be dependent on the the parent on this way, instead, it should have a shared model, which it can ask questions about the state of the UI. Each label would then be provided with information it needs to ascertain the state (such as its current x/y position in the grid for example)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach might be to separate your logic from the Swing GUI library. For example, defining a `CellContainer` class that contains `Cell` objects, which can be updated before each render (where in the update you can update `Cell`s from `CellContainer` however you wish). You could then have `CellContainerPanel` and a `CellLabel` class that extend the appropriate Swing class which take a reference to `CellContainer` and `Cell` each which just draw the state that their references make available.

Comment: Since `Graphics` is a shared resource, coping a reference from the parent will give you the same instance of `Graphics` that the cell panel will use.  Since the translation is done automatically before the component is painted any way...it's all just repeating work that is done normally. Having said that, your second suggestion is far better and is moving into line with the concept of the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was thinking incorrectly that JPanel was painted after it's children and tried to extend his example of working around not being drawn first... That is incorrect though I'll remove it.

Comment: If I understand corrrectly, this would mean that each `Cell` reference would have to contain state information that is dependent on its neighbors - precisely the redundancy I wanted to avoid. I see how that makes everything align with MVC, as @MadProgrammer suggests, and understand decoupling business logic from the UI is a good thing to do. Thanks for the hint, I hope I can implement your suggestion without much trouble. For starters, would it be a good idea to make the `CellLabel` check for the `Cell` state when painting with `paintComponent`?

Comment: @MHaaZ Why would each cell need to know anything?  It's not the cells responsibility to know what's neighbour is up to, it's up to the cells "container".  Start by separating your logic from your view, allow the view to render the requirements of the logic/state and the logic/state to managed separately. You are by decoupling each of your components from each other, remove the logic into a different layer, it should be capable of operating independently from the UI and the UI should be able to use multiple different instances of this model

Comment: @MadProgrammer Separating logic/state and view is precisely what I'm trying (and failing) to do. The `CellContainer` is the one who knows how the neighborhood of a `Cell` looks, so it should partially control painting in the `CellLabel`s (they can't do it for themselves: if the `Cell` they point to doesn't know anything about its neighbours (I agree it shouldn't), how can a `CellLabel` paint itself fully?)
And I'm back to square one: how to tell a Swing component (`CellLabel`) to paint something depending on some external state (neigborhood) that isn't contained in its `Cell` reference?

Comment: Each `CellLabel` needs to ask the `CellContainer` about how it should paint based on the `Cell` that it represents...

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, your paintComponent function needs to call super.paintComponent(g);

The last time I wrote a program with swing, i declared a static graphics object in a class that everything could access (this is probably a horrible thing to do, but it was a workaround which helped me to complete my task). Instead of storing the information inside of a two dimensional array, store "information" objects inside the array. Those information objects (object x, for example) can contain all the information about the cell itself, as well as a "draw(g)" method. That draw method can dictate how this cell is drawn. In the paintComponent function, you can now call

```
//where g is the graphics object
for (array x : array of arrays) {
    for (informationObject y : x) {
        y.draw(g);
    }
}
```

Now you can do all the calculations inside the object itself, instead of having to deal with obtaining external information and doing calculations outside. (Then, the code will be easier to debug as well)

Comment: Yep, and I do that. I'll reflect that in the code, thanks for the reminder :-)

Comment: Are you storing your y cells (which could be coded as objects with a "paint me" function) in any sort of list? If you choose to do so, you may be able to use an enhanced for loop to draw those cells.

Comment: The cells that contain the "important" information (used to decide what and how to paint) are stored in a two-dimensional array. Could you specify what you mean about storing cells as objects with a "paint me" function? How would that function paint/be painted (with which `Graphics` context?)